# Can I fix 'Sleep verb "Suspend" not supported' without disabling secure boot?

Tags: linux-mint, hibernate, suspend

I'm running Linux Mint 20.2 XFCE on an external USB4 drive alongside my Windows 10 internal NVMe SSD.

I went through an automated script written for my hardware to enable hibernate on my laptop before realizing I'd need to disable secure boot to get it to work properly. I can't disable for a host of reasons (employer, win10 encryption, etc), and now I am unable to suspend because of the `Sleep verb 'Suspend' not supported` error message. Are there any fixes for this message that don't involve enabling secure boot? It would most likely involve disabling hibernate, but I can't find many resources on that subject.

/sys/power/state:
`freeze mem`

/sys/power/disk:
`[disabled]` (part of the problem and why I can't suspend?)

Part of /etc/default/grub that has given the one person with my error message a problem: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=“quiet splash”`

Power Manager settings part 1:
[Settings>Power Manager>General](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9AAIK.png)

Power Manager settings part 2:
[Settings>Power Manager>System](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3vsg.png)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Though I have found it difficult to enable hibernation in Linux, sometimes requiring adding space to a separate partition for the hibernation file, *sleep* is readily enabled (though it does use a continual trickle of power, unlike hibernation). See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/602406/guide-on-how-to-enable-hibernation-on-linux-mint-20-cinnamon-ubuntu-20-and-pre and https://frameboxxindore.com/android/how-do-i-put-linux-mint-to-sleep.html

Comment: @DrMoishePippik my problem is that before I tried to enable hibernation suspend worked perfectly, and now it’s not, so I need to figure out what settings to change so that suspend works again. The dconf editor tip in that article is helpful, I’ll use that to ensure I’m suspending on sleep once I get suspend working again.